# Rails scraping errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

Firstly it is showing error I have use `#Watir.default_timeout = 900` also I try change the time in config file inside webrick still it doesn't work

The errors are

> Net::ReadTimeout

Secondly for the next error I even tried changing port number still it doesn't work

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 70 55):

I want to list all the seller name and price but it only list 2 sellers name and price I want them all

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'phantomjs'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new: chrome
browser.window.maximize
browser.goto "url"
browser.div(: class => 'sellCont').uls.each do |list |
    puts list.lis.first.text# For dealer name
    puts list.li(: class => 'price')# For price
end
browser.close
```

Comment: it looks like you `browser.close` inside cycling and next step can not connect to `browser`

Comment: OH sorry i have put browser.close outside only but it was still showing error

Comment: please review your example and fix some errors (it is better if it is one to one as in you real code). For example `Watir::Browser.new: chrome`, `div(: class => 'sellCont')` is invalid ruby code.

Comment: THis I have seen from watir website only Watir::Browser.new: chrome what is the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting all required data when you load given url first time without click on any link or button on browser?

Comment: Sir,When I am clicking on the anchor tag then i get all the  data ..<a ng-click="product.sellersViewAll = !product.sellersViewAll;product.scrollToSellers()" ng-if="product.product.other_sellers.values.length > 2" tabindex="0" class="">
              <!-- ngIf: product.sellersViewAll -->
              <!-- ngIf: !product.sellersViewAll --><h2 ng-if="!product.sellersViewAll">View All<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></h2><!-- end ngIf: !product.sellersViewAll --></a>

Comment: ok add following lines in your code: browser.div(:class => 'sellCont').a.h2.click

Answer (score 0):

As you said your example one-to-one as your code. It is really strange because it does not look like a valid ruby code. This code works in my console (`irb`)

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.window.maximize
browser.goto "https://paytm.com/shop/p/gionee-e7-mini-black-MOBGIONEE-E7-MIHAPP44414CBBDB36C?psearch=organic%7Cundefined%7Cgionee%20e7%7Cgrid"
browser.div(:class => 'sellCont').uls.each do |list |
    puts list.li.first.text# For dealer name
    puts list.li(:class => 'price')# For price
end
browser.close
```

Pay attention that you don't use phantomjs (maybe you need it in general but not in the given example) so it was removed. And I require `watir-webdriver` not `watir` (I just take it from one of my project)

Comment: You should set chrome driver (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and set gems selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver